# Show that for every continuous function $f$ from $[0,\pi /2]$ into $[0,1]$ there exists $x$ such that $f(x) = \sin x$.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Show that for every continuous function $f$ from $[0,\pi /2]$ into $[0,1]$ there exists $x$ such that $f(x) = \sin x$.

Is this question equivalent to $f:[0,\pi /2] \to [0,1]: x \mapsto \sin x$

For the solution can we directly say since $(\Bbb R,|.|)$~$(\Bbb R,d), d(x,y) = |\arctan x -\arctan y|$~$|.|$, it is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$g(x)=f(x)-sin(x)$, $g(0)\geq 0$, $g(\pi/2)=f(\pi/2)-1\leq 0$ IVT implies there exists $x$ such that $g(x)=0$.